# Heimdall/JOdin: "We could not obtain the PIT file. We tried, but it didn't work."

Tags: rooting, linux, odin, samsung-galaxy-s-6, heimdall

I'm trying to root my Samsung S6, but I don't have a Windows computer. Luckily, [JOdin works on Linux too](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134152/how-to-root-samsung-s6-using-linux) and it connects to my phone, so I am now much closer to my goal.

But now I am facing a new challenge: JOdin says: **"We could not obtain the pit file. We tried, but it didn't work."** The CLI output of the JOdin's offline version reports the following (excerpt):

```
[VERBOSE]Heimdall Device detected!
[ERROR]ANALYSIS DETECTED ERROR:Failed to send data!
[VERBOSE]Did not find pit
[INTERACTION][SHOWERROR] Title:Could not obtain pit.
Message:We could not obtain the pit file. We tried, but it didn't work.
```

The JOdin support seems to consist of [this 30+ page long forum post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=49133090#post49133090), which is why I hope to get more useful answers here.

1. [JOdin relies on](https://casual-dev.com/2014/01/04/jodin3-web-browser-or-offline-flashing-tool/) the [Heimdall](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/) package, and that one has a list of supported devices that *does not include* the S6. I suppose this is part of the cause of the problem. I use JOdin v1035 and Heimdall v1.4.0-0.
2. Indeed, when I run only Heimdall, I succeed in connecting the phone but the PIT download fails; the only relevant log line is `ERROR: Setting up interface failed!`
3. Full log output is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/hfGy0hm0) and [here is the verbose output](http://pastebin.com/raw/iu2QKHi8).
4. The command `sudo heimdall print-pit --verbose --stdout-errors --usb-log-level debug` as suggested in comments produces [this output](http://pastebin.com/raw/FcnBd7MG) which is beyond my skill to interpret.

I dare not download a "random" PIT file from the Internet; the risk of choosing the wrong one is too high, and those I've found are behind a [sketchy-looking Vietnamese paywall](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/download-samsung-galaxy-s6-pit-file-g920fiklstw8-84262/). Google also pointed me to methods that rely on `adb shell` and requires root ... but having root is the goal I'm chasing right now.

How do I download the PIT from my phone?

**Update:** I've managed to root my phone [using a Windows computer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/help/trying-to-root-sm-g920f-using-linux-t3293361#post64816710) and therefore I no longer *urgently* need this working on Linux. I will probably need it the next time I have to fiddle with the phone (e.g. when an Android update is available) but *for now* I will abandon this challenge.

Comment: @BoLawson the normal output is [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/hfGy0hm0) and [here is the verbose output](http://pastebin.com/raw/iu2QKHi8). It doesn't really give any additional hints...

Comment: @beeshyams The Droid News site suggests using Odin (didn't work) or using TermEmulator+BusyBox (requires root!), and the XDA link (thanks!) lists _five_ different PIT's and I can't tell which one I should choose - as I said, I'm afraid that choosing wrong will brick my phone.

Comment: First post on XDA link clearly says " original pit for a G920F dévice open firmware:
ZEROFLTE_EUR_OPEN.pit :

Comment: Have a look at this....http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/general/root-pingpongroot-s6-root-tool-t3103016

Comment: @BoLawson thanks, I added [the output](http://pastebin.com/raw/FcnBd7MG) in the post (list item 4).

Comment: It's a communication error between libusb and your device. Umm, try different ports/cables. Honestly though there are many things that could be. I will keep my eye out for more information while traveling the world wide web

Comment: I was thinking about it there might be another program blocking it. Example is kies and odin even though they are from the same family they hate each other and can block the other from working. TLDR there might be another similar program keeping it from communicating.

Comment: Interesting idea, and yet: isn't Kies a Windows installation? I certainly didn't install anything like this in Linux. I wonder if some combination of hardware (socket/cable/driver/mainboard) is somehow only almost compatible.

Comment: Yep kies is for Mac and Windows but it was just ment as an example nothing more.  Some insight into your logs #2 - #5 ended with -7 which = LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT meaning operation timed out. #6 ended with -1 which = LIBUSB_ERROR_IO meaning Input/output error. Now that your rooted (congratulations you totally need an aircraft carrier with a mission accomplished banner in the backround) it does not really matter but for future issues you could also pull kernel logs specifically Dmesg. It might give little bit more info.

Comment: I have similar problems with a Samsung J5 phone. The hint from @BoLawson to check the output of `dmesg` was good. The cable seemed to be broken, because the phone was connecting and disconnecting forever. With another cable at least that issue is gone. But still the PIT file problem. And now that I have found a PIT file which I think is the right one, Jodin and Heimdall still don’t copy the content of the TWRP file to the phone. I don’t want to install windows. Last time, with a Sony telephone, I used [Wine and it worked](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/156101/93158).